# How to stop repeating objects in @ManyToOne JPA?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

My Parent class :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Child> child;

public List<Child> getChild() {
    return child;
}

public void setChild(List<Child> child) {
    this.child = child;
}
```

My Child class :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID")
private Parent parent;

public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:227) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
... 38 common frames omitted
```

In browser :

[image]

Its look like @OneToMany from the parent entity calling child object fine. But @ManyToOne in child entity doing the same by calling parent object again and its repeating. How to avoid this problem?

Comment: You aren't repeating anything in JPA. You are repeating in your generation of JSON, which is nothing to do with the JPA API.

Comment: Yes Neil got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [@JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) and [@JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) like so:

#### Parent

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Child> child;
```

#### Child

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID")
private Parent parent;
```

#### What is happening?

This has nothing to do with JPA. Your @Entity model provides methods to access the fields. To represent them in an API, you serialize them. The serializer is not aware of the entity at that level (to where it would have knowledge of the persistence layer. That would breach the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Therefore, you must provide the serializer hints just as you do with @ManyToOne, @OneToMany on your entity model. The serializer iterates through the get methods on your class, and calls them. Without hints, you end up with a circular reference because you call the parent, then get the child. Once serializing the child, you call the parent again.

#### From the references

[@JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html): Annotation used to indicate that annotated property is part of two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is **"parent" (or "forward") link.**

[@JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html): Annotation used to indicate that associated property is part of two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is **"child" (or "back") link**

Comment: No problem. If this worked, please remember to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Having a doubt can't we do this in JPA itself?

Comment: It has nothing to do with JPA. JPA is representing the resource. When you serialize, by default, the methods are called. You have to "hint" at the serializer so it has additional details about how it should serialize.

Comment: I've added an explanation to better explain. Hopefully it is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In your child class ignore serializing/desirializing your parent using @JsonIgnore

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID")
private Parent parent;

public Parent getParent() {
   return parent;
}

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
 }
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: does anybody know the difference between upper solution and this solution ? which is brian's solution and Amer's solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The annotations proposed from the acceptable answer and others are basically telling spring boot to skip it from reading them. Yes, it was able to resolve the looping issue but it doesn't entire resolve the problem which is to return the expected json output.

*Instead I made some twists with these implementations and it works for me!*

**Interchange the reference annotation**

- Parent Entity -> @JsonManagedReference
- Child Entity  -> @JsonBackReference

**Code Snippet Example:**

Parent.java (class)

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //"parent" -> is the name defined by child class
private List<Child> childs;
```

Child.java (class)

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") //parent_id is the foreign key for child
private Parent parent; //object name defined from Parent class
```

*The interchange above works for me.*